# How to add a vector to be a column using dplyr (examples given)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got some data. I want to add a column, but not in the regular way.

```
data <- data.frame(month_num = 1:12, month_name = month.abb)
data

       month_num month_name
1          1        Jan
2          2        Feb
3          3        Mar
4          4        Apr
5          5        May
6          6        Jun
7          7        Jul
8          8        Aug
9          9        Sep
10        10        Oct
11        11        Nov
12        12        Dec
```

Now, I want to add a third column to this data. For example I want to make the following vector a column within `data`:

```
sentiment = c(rep("cold", 3), rep("hot", 6), rep("cold", 3)
```

What I would normally do (in baseR) is one of the following:

1. Add it using `$`

   ```
   data$sentiment <- sentiment
   ```
2. Add it via column index creation

   ```
   data[,3] <- sentiment
   ```
3. Add it in initial creation

   ```
   data.frame(month_num = 1:12, month_name = month.abb, sentiment = sentiment)
   ```

Yes, `data.table` also has this nicely done within its reference semantics.

```
data <- data.table(month_num = 1:12, month_name = month.abb)

data[,`:=`(sentiment = sentiment)]

data

    month_num month_name sentiment
 1:         1        Jan      cold
 2:         2        Feb      cold
 3:         3        Mar      cold
 4:         4        Apr       hot
 5:         5        May       hot
 6:         6        Jun       hot
 7:         7        Jul       hot
 8:         8        Aug       hot
 9:         9        Sep       hot
10:        10        Oct      cold
11:        11        Nov      cold
12:        12        Dec      cold
```

However, I don't want to add it in this way. I want to use dplyr related functions to do this task. Is there any function within `dplyr` that will let me perform this task of column creation?

**NOTE:** `mutate()` will not work! (or as I know of it right now).

```
data%>%
mutate(sentiment = sentiment)

   month_num month_name   V3 sentiment
1          1        Jan cold      cold
2          2        Feb cold      cold
3          3        Mar cold      cold
4          4        Apr  hot       hot
5          5        May  hot       hot
6          6        Jun  hot       hot
7          7        Jul  hot       hot
8          8        Aug  hot       hot
9          9        Sep  hot       hot
10        10        Oct cold      cold
11        11        Nov cold      cold
12        12        Dec cold      cold
```

As you can see the column is duplicated and I'm not really sure why that's happening. Perhaps it has to do with the number of unique values in `sentiment`?

**All in all, is there a way to accomplish this within dplyr using `mutate()` or other related functions?**

Comment: `data %>% mutate(sentiment = sentiment)` works fine for me

Comment: Very strange that I was getting the `V3` column output. Any ideas why that might have happened? It's also working fine for me now too.

Comment: What's happen when you remove this line `data[,3] <- sentiment`?

Comment: Oops! Did i leave that column in there accidentally? Time for me to either delete this post or find another example. Thanks for pointing that gaff on my end.

Comment: Though I think @ANG figured out the problem, another way would be to use `library(tibble); add_column(data, sentiment)`.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way I know is using the function `case_when`:

```
data <- data.frame(month_num = 1:12, month_name = month.abb)
data
sentiment = c(rep("cold", 3), rep("hot", 6), rep("cold", 3)

data <- data %>% 
    mutate(sentiment=case_when(
        month_num<=3 | month_num>=10 ~ "cold",
        month_num>=4 & month_num<=9 ~ "hot"
    ))
```

Comment: The thing is, i would like to avoid using conditional statements like this. I want to be able to simply paste in the vector to be the column. I only gave a basic example with hot and cold because it was suppose to be short. I might have many different values instead of just those 2 values. `case_when()` doesn't look nice in this event. `ANG` in the comment section of the OP has pointed out that `mutate(sentiment = sentiment)` works, but it's not obvious to me why i was getting the `V3` column.

Comment: I have no V3 column using `mutate(sentiment=sentiment)`, sorry.

Comment: Strange, i will look again tomorrow if I can reproduce my problem.